# How to reboot linux system (Debian) by using php

Tags: php, linux

I want to execute a linux command using PHP

myfile.php:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

It works!

But when I change linux command from `ls` to `reboot`, nothing happens!

So I tried to find another solution:

mycode.html:

```
<button type="button" onclick="/var/www/myscript.sh">Click Me!</button>
```

myscript.sh:

```
sudo reboot
```

It doesn't work, too!

May anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Obviously, your user, from which your script was executed, has not enough rights to execute `reboot` (or similar) command

Comment: Did you try to add the server user to sudoers?

Comment: @sal00m: It's a very bad idea to globally add sudo permissions to the server user. The sudoers file allows to whitelist certain commands.

Comment: @urzeit, yes i'm agree with this

Answer (score 6):

By default, reboot command must be executed as root. You would be able to do that if your web server ran under root account, but this is very unusual proposition.

Typically, web server runs under limited account which cannot do much, and certainly cannot execute reboot. If you *really* want to do that, it must be done with great care. Standard way to provide this is to create special wrapper (most likely suid) which checks for many conditions before allowing to run under elevated permissions.

Another solution is to have PHP create flag file or insert special database entry, which would be checked by another service running as root, noticing that flag and finally executing reboot.

Answer (score 5):

As @mvp says you cannot execute reboot as non root user.

A simple way to do this is with a cron job.

Your myscript.sh will be:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/reboot.now
```

Then create a cron job that checks if this file exists:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /tmp/reboot.now ]; then
  rm -f /tmp/reboot.now
  /sbin/shutdown -r now 
fi
```

Then configure your server to execute this script every minute

```
* * * * * /usr/local/sbin/reboot.sh
```

And dont forget to give execute permissions to the file of course.

Hope it helps

EDITED: Of course your `myscript.sh` can be a php with `fopen` and `fclose` instead

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Sal00m's answer

**ROOT** crontab

```
* * * * * /usr/local/sbin/checkreboot.sh
```

checkreboot.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /var/www/html/reboot.server ]; then
  rm -f /var/www/html/reboot.server
  /sbin/shutdown -r now 
fi
```

reboot.php

```
<?php
$filehandler = fopen("/var/www/html/reboot.server",'w');
fwrite($filehandler,"Reboot now\n");
fclose($filehandler);
?>
```

From http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/shutdown-and-reboot-linux-system-via-php-script-713379/#post3486126