# iptables not exec by Apache on php file

Tags: php, linux, centos

I have a CentOS system with PHP on it and I want to use the `exec()` command to run a program like `iptables` and `reboot` etc.

Whilst some command work like `exec ('arp')`, some others do not work, like `exec ('reboot')`.

I have done some debugging and get a message like `(it need root user )`.

So I have edited the sudores file and made it NOPASSWORD for the Apache user but nothing has changed.

Comment: Are you doing `exec('sudo iptables')`?

Comment: Yes I exec(sudo ...)

Comment: Check if this thread helps you out:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19109523/4340845

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea security wise. Your granting the Apache user access to do anything on your box using the `sudo` command without a password!

Answer (score 2):

I hope you haven't edited the ***sudoers*** file with a normal text editor. The sudoers file needs to be edited using ***visudo*** command. For more help on editing *sudoers* please follow  this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos

Comment: I edited with visudo and edited by text editer